# Using a Spinner to switch to another Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, spinner

I am making an android app that has two activities, a drums activity, and a piano activity.

I have already gotten all of the UI done and even sound functionality for the drums.

What I want to know is how do I use a Spinner Widget to change from the drums to the piano?

I have my spinner all set up to where it asks you to choose an instrument and it says Drums and Piano, all I need is the implementation.

I am new to multiple activities with multiple UI's so any help would be awesome.

This is what I have tried but it is not right:

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener 
{

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
    {
      Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
          parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() + " View Selected",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() == "Drums")
      {
          Intent i = new Intent(this, BeatLooper.java);
          startActivity(i);
      }

      if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() == "Piano")
      {
          Intent i = new Intent(this, PianoActivity.java);
          startActivity(i);
      }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) 
    {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

This code is inside the BeatLooper.java file which is where my Drums and their implementation is. I want to use the switcher to switch to my PianoActivity.java file, which is where my Piano implementation is.

I have 2 .xml files in my layout: main.xml for BeatLooper.java and piano.xml for PianoActivity.java

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing the user has to go through 3 clicks to do this switch (menu, change, and then selection). You could just put a "switch to drums" or "switch to piano" menu option, reducing the number of actions necessary to accomplish this. Just a random suggestion from browsing the Android questions.

Answer (score 0):

replace PianoActivity.java and BeatlLooper.java with `PianoActivity.class` and `BeatLooper.class`

EDIT**

Actually, assuming your `MyOnItemSelectedListener` is an inner class inside of your activity, you need to use `new Intent(MyActivityName.this, PianoActivity.class)`, replacing MyActivityName with the actual name of your `Activity` class. Normally, a simple `this` will do because, in Java, it references the current object, and the simple cases are where you simply reference your Activity from somewhere inside of it.

Comment: when I make it say Intent i = new Intent(this, BeatLooper.class) or PianoActivity.class it gives the error: The constructor Intent(BeatLooper.MyOnItemSelectedListener, Class<BeatLooper>) is undefined.